# Генератор карт в консоли, с ASCII симолами - C++

Tags: c++, github, генераторы

Сделал свой первый небольшой, но интересный проект, генератор карт в консоли. Генератор генерирует комнаты и коридоры, которые соединяют эти комнаты. Для генерации использую табличный алгоритм. Реализовано с ООП. Код прокомментирован. Собственно в чем вопрос: хочу попросить вас посмотреть мой проект, (ссылка на github ниже) и сказать, что можно улучшить, или можете сделать это в самом github-e. Хочу улучшить качество своего кода. Также хочу узнать что можно было сделать проще/лучше в самом проекте, и может как лучше свои проекты оформлять на github-e (на нем содаю репозиторий первый раз). Буду очень рад всей помощи!!!
[Ссылка на github](https://github.com/Starikov32/MapGenerator)

Comment: Вообще вопрос не чёткий и скорее всего вы не получите хороший ответ на него. Напишу пару своих замечаний: переменные класса, какие-то в большой регистре, какие-то нет. Тоже с методами. Некоторые методы очень длинные и выглядят как копипаст: generateCoridor, willCombine, willCoridorCreate. Вместо char ** и Element *, лучше использовать умные указатели или контейнеры stl.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос должен быть самодостаточным, обсуждаемый код должен быть в самом вопросе. См. описание метки [инспекция-кода]  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info Связанное обсуждение не Мете [Можно ли на "StackOverflow на русском" просить обзоры (review) своего кода расположенного на GitHub?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6829/23044)

Comment: Хотелось бы добавить, маленький совет, не пишите всю программу в конструкторе. виртуальные методы в конструкторах не работают, ошибки нормально обработать в них тоже не особо получится. вообще конструкторы и деструкторы должны быть легкими.

Comment: Unick, PavelNewSky, Спасибо за те советы которые дали, буду учится дальше!)

Comment: Используйте единый стиль при написании кода, если именуете переменные на английском, то int nomer быть не должно, если ставите { с новой строки, то везде (включая if/while..). "// Для отладки" обычно используют #ifdef _DEBUG. public, protected, private - общепринятый порядок) Меньше самоочевидных комментариев, нет нужды комментировать деструктор "// удаляем данные в куче..." это его стандартная работа. "Тут немного сначала непонятные формулы,
 но если нарисовать чертеж посидеть и подумать можно понять откуда я их взял" - такого не должно быть) А так, код работает - вы молодец, успехов.

Comment: Тег ооп у вас явно лишний. Код написан в процедурном стиле. По счастливому стечению обстоятельств, ровно такую же задачу рассматривала банда четырех в третей главе Design Patterns. Рекомендую к прочтению, если не всю книгу, то хотя бы эту главу. Тогда, возможно, для следующей версии программы тег ооп будет в тему :)

Comment: @goldstar-labs, спасибо за советы, комментировал проект в первый раз, раньше такого не делал, поэтому много ошибок в этом. Про #ifdef _DEBUG ничего не знал, поэтому не использовал, думаю самое время теперь узнать).

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, спасибо за советы, особенно за книгу, обязательно найду ее прочитаю ту главу, а потом может и всю книгу если понравится. Буду подправлять постепенно

Comment: @Марк Стариков, это классика. Надо читать даже если не понравится:) Элементарно чтобы знать что значат для адептов ооп слова "мост", "одиночка", "посетитель" и т.п.

Comment: @yrhetatejlb, уже посмотрел книгу, обязательно прочту после той книги что читаю сейчас, спасибо за совет!